# Sitecore Item web api getting 404

Tags: sitecore

I am using [Sitecore Item Web API](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Sitecore%20Item%20Web%20API/SitecoreItemWebApi12.aspx) module after installing package, I have tried `http://[hostname]/-/item/v1/?query=/sitecore/content/*` this URL. But I keep getting 404.

Any input please?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please update website setting in your Sitecore.ItemWebApi.config file  under include folder as given below.

```
<site name="website">
        <patch:attribute name="itemwebapi.mode">StandardSecurity</patch:attribute>
        <patch:attribute name="itemwebapi.access">ReadOnly</patch:attribute>
        <patch:attribute name="itemwebapi.allowanonymousaccess">true</patch:attribute>
      </site>
```

I think it will work for you.